# Is there a way to disallow a firewal to specific domain in symfony

Tags: symfony, security, firewall

I am setting the security for my api. I need to secure the api URL.
So, ask for autentication for the url mydomain.com/api/.
BUT if the request come from the same domain (mydomain.com) I want to turn off the autentication.

I tried to use the host key and put a regular expresion that says: when the host not contain "mydomain". But it did not work.

```
firewalls:
        api:
            pattern:   ^/api
            host: ^((?!mydomain).)*$
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            lexik_jwt:
                authorization_header:
                    enabled: true
                    prefix:  Bearer
```

```
firewalls:
        api:
            pattern:   ^/api
            host: #???????
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            lexik_jwt:
                authorization_header:
                    enabled: true
                    prefix:  Bearer
```

I expected that the api firewall work when the request come outside mydomain. And not work when request come from mydomain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to reverse your logic.

Build two firewalls :

- The first one intercepts requests incoming from your domain and disable authentication for those.
- The second one catches all remaining requests and ask for authentication.